# How to separate graphs and then plot their on one graphical window?

Tags: r, plot

I have three time series `md1`, `md2`, `md3`, three ARIMA models `f1`, `f2`, `f3`. I'd like to plot  AR- и МA-roots of ARIMA models in one graphical window.   I have tried:

```
library(forecast)

md1 <- runif(100, 0, 1)
md2 <- runif(100, 0, 1)
md3 <- runif(100, 0, 1)

f1<-arima(md1,order=c(1,1,0))
f2<-arima(md2,order=c(1,1,0))
f3<-arima(md3,order=c(2,1,2))

par(mfrow = c(1,3))
#  AR- и МA-roots of ARIMA models
plot(f1) # one graph
plot(f2) # one graph
plot(f3) # two graphs
```

As the result, I see the last plot only, i.e. `plot(f3)`. Of course, I can add the `windows()` command

```
plot(f2); windows()
```

and make a new graphical window for `plot(f3)`. Also, I have tried to change options of the `par()` function, likes

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
```

and tried to create a new object

```
 p3 <- plot(f3)
```

but expected result wasn't achieved.

**Question**. How to separate two graphs generated by the `plot(f3)` command?

**Expected result:**

**[image: Expected result:]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer on my question [here](https://dzone.com/articles/plotting-characteristic-roots). This is the code which was not included to the package `forecast` by the author.